# Oraclevsswriter service not running

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing the error 1297 when trying to start the oraclevsswriter service. The error is like a privilege that the service requires to function properly doesn't exist in the service account configuration. It is also given to use services.mnc and secpol.mnc to view the service configuration and account configuration.
Please help me solve this...

Tried  a week ago but couldn't solve this. Badly need a solution for this.

Comment: What steps are you following to start this service? Has it worked before or you have just installed it and it is throwing errors? If the second option, what steps did you followed to install the service? What is your environment (OS, versions, other services, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before. Can you please run secpol.msc and check Local Policies->User Rights Assignment->Back up files and directories (double click this). Check to see is Backup Operators is listed. If it is not, add "Backup Operators" to "Back up Files and Directories" and try to start the service again.